# WCF not using all cores with Visual Studio 2010 Load Testing

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I've developed a WCF service, and I'm testing it for performance using Visual Studio 2010 Load Testing infrastructure. I have a Quad Core Intel Q6600 on my desktop and, for now, the WCF is hosted on a console application for testing purpose. While executing the tests, I have 1 core at 100%, and the other 3 between 25 to 60%. The HostApplication.exe process for only brief instances passes 25%, and I don't know why. Why isn't WCF spreading the calls to the other cores, so that I don't have a CPU bottleneck? Shouldn't I have the HostApplication.exe spread over more than 1 core, limited at 25%?
I have configures VS2010 Load Testing with 25 users, and they are calling 2 methods. On the service implementation of the Methods I use, I have the following configured for ServiceBehaviour:

```
  [ServiceBehavior(TransactionIsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted, 
    InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete=false)]
```

I've also defined the serviceThrottling behaviour for the service. Below is my app.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
      <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="SimpleBinding" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <netTcpBinding>
              <binding name="DefaultTCPBinding" closeTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00"
                    sendTimeout="01:00:00" transactionFlow="true" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    maxBufferSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
                <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="01:00:00" />
              </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="ScriptBindig" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
              <endpointBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="WebScriptBehavior">
                          <enableWebScript />
                    </behavior>
              </endpointBehaviors>
              <serviceBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
                          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetBinding="webHttpBinding"
                                httpGetBindingConfiguration="" />
                          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="64" maxConcurrentSessions="400"
                                maxConcurrentInstances="464" />
                    </behavior>
              </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
              <service behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior" name="Implementation.TestingAppImplementation">
                    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultTCPBinding"
                          name="TestingAppTCPEndpoint" contract="Interfaces.ITestingApp" />
                    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                          name="TestingAppMex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                    <endpoint address="ws" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                          bindingConfiguration="SimpleBinding" name="TestingApp" contract="Interfaces.ITestingApp" />
                    <host>
                          <baseAddresses>
                                <add baseAddress="net.tcp://desk01:9878/TestingAppService" />
                                <add baseAddress="http://desk01:9876/TestingAppService/" />
                          </baseAddresses>
                    </host>
              </service>
        </services>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
                      logMalformedMessages="true"
                      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Tks so much for any help. **ANY advice** would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are your two methods you're testing known to be CPU-bound?

Comment: Forgive the ignorance, but how can I tell? All I do basic database operations. They are all transactions on the database. I do use Enteprise Library's logging objects to log to XML only exceptions. But during the 2-3 minutes testing, in 6000 method calls, I have no exceptions.

Comment: I believe you have just answered the question.  Database operations will be magnitudes slower than CPU operations.  The bear's share of your thread's will likely be taken doing the database calls.  Put the process under a profile and that should tell you for sure where your code's time is being spent.

Comment: @Jesse Which profiler should I use? Can I do this with VS2010? I've never done such an analysis. Tks for your time

Comment: Tks.. I'm downloading it... but, even if it's the database that is slowing down my service, shouldn't that be spread between the 4 cores, since I have 25 threads making calls? Why would I have 1 core at 100%? Tks

Comment: As I understand it, the `ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` is what gets you the multithreading, but without seeing everything going on, can't be sure of what would be blocking you.  If you have a self-hosted server (or a logging method), you can see if different threads are spawned by outputting `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I transfered the WCF service from a self-hosting executable to IIS/AppFabric, with the same exact code and database modeling, I was able to use all 4 cores without a problem. I got great performance after transferring.
Tks

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it looks like your bottleneck is the database.

If this is the case, the best optimisation you could do would be avoiding disk access by caching data in memory.

Since you already use Enterprise Libray you could use that. We have used that on several projects, it worked well for us.

Comment: I'm sorry, but help me understand. How can it be database if I have the host application taking up a single core at 100%? If I have 25 users making calls to the WCF Service, shouldn't take be distributed between the 4 cores? Tks for your time

Comment: It could be that your database is tied to a single core